# add a dot in 4th index for each string

Tags: python, pandas

i want to add a dot to each string in dataframe,for example `49454170` become `4945.4170`

below frame:

```
       Missed Trades
0        49454170
1        49532878
2        49511387
3        49451350
4        49402211
5        49403961
6        49331707
7        49320696
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach using [`str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) and join back the resulting lists with [`str.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
df['Missed Trades'].str.findall(r'(\d{4})').str.join('.')

0    4945.4170
1    4953.2878
2    4951.1387
3    4945.1350
4    4940.2211
5    4940.3961
6    4933.1707
7    4932.0696
Name: MissedTrades, dtype: object
```

Comment: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work -

```
df['Missed Trades'] = df['Missed Trades'].astype(int) / 10000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Missed Trades'] = df['Missed Trades'].map(lambda x : x[0:4]+'.'+x[4:8])

       Missed Trades
0        4945.4170
1        4953.2878
2        4951.1387
3        4945.1350
4        4940.2211
5        4940.3961
6        4933.1707
7        4932.0696
```